# try/catch não "pegando" a Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, exceção

Eu estou usando JPA e estava tentando criar uma EntityManager, e tava testando alguns tratamentos de expcetions em uma classe minha. Porém, eu to com um problema, que a exception não está sendo "pega" pelo catch.

```
  public static boolean openConnection() {
    try {
        if (emf == null) {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sysbex"); //linha do erro
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            transaction = em.getTransaction();
        }

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("passou aqui"); //essa linha não executa 
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque?
ps: Já tentei trocar o tipo de exceção, e também nada.

Comment: Alguma exceção está sendo lançada? Se você colocar um `System.out.println("Chegou aqui");` após o `}` do `if (emf == null)`, essa linha é executada?

Comment: @carlosfigueira Sim, uma stackTrace é lançada no console. Se eu colocar o SOUT depois do emf == null, ele executa, mas se colocar depois do `emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sysbex");` ele não executa.

Comment: Pode postar o *stack trace* da exceção?

Comment: E uma dúvida besta (mas que já me afetou). Você fez um *clean*, *build* e *redeploy* total da solução?

Comment: Coloque o stackTrace completo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o correto seria colocar o try/catch dentro do if ! Talvez esse seja o problema, tente assim:

```
public static boolean openConnection() {
    if (emf == null)  {
        try {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sysbex"); //linha do erro
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            transaction = em.getTransaction();
        }
   catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("passou aqui"); //essa linha não executa 
        return false;
    }
}
    return true;
}
```